# How to get rid of/override add row popup title on Kendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to remove title from add row popup on Kendo. I managed it in some other popups that are not a new row popup, cant seem to figure this out.
[image]

This is the code I have for the popup

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="popup-editor-servers">
<p style="padding-left:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Add Server</p>
<div class="k-edit-label">
    <label for="txt-host">Name:</label>
</div>

<!-- textbox editor for field: "LastName" -->
<!-- field: "LastName" is not included as a grid column -->
<input type="text" id="txt-host" class="k-input k-textbox" data-bind="value:Host">
```

I would not mind removing it completely but I guess as long as I have access to the title I can do anything.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Below code does the job. Grid is

```
<div id="grid-acl"
         data-role="grid"
         data-auto-bind="true"
         data-sortable="{allowUnsort: false}"
         data-filterable="false"
         data-editable='{mode: "popup", template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())}' ,
         data-groupable="false"
         data-columns='[
        { field: "Name", title: "AD User", width: "400px" },
         @*{ field: "Sid", title: "SID" }, *@
        ]'
         data-bind="source: dataSource, events: { change: onChange, dataBound: onDataBound }">
    </div>
```

Popup content is here :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="popup-editor-servers">
<p style="padding-left:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Add Server</p>
<div class="k-edit-label">
<label for="txt-host">Name:</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="txt-host" class="k-input k-textbox" data-bind="value:Host">
```

On button click:

```
create: function (event) {
            var grid = $("#grid-servers").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.options.editable = {
                mode: "popup", window: { title: "Add Server" }, template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor-servers").html())
            };

            grid.addRow();
        },
```